# Azure container instance, to stop after data processed and start back for every one hour

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-logic-apps, azure-container-instances

I have feed job as a pod on AKS, triggered by Logic App for every one hour. Purpose- The data will be processed and updated on Azure blob storage. Planned to move this to Azure container instance(ACI)  , so have automated via Jenkins to deploy the ACI and it works as expected. Now looking to stop Azure container instance once the data processing is completed and start back prior to an hour. so logic App can initiate the trigger.  Shall we have job in Jenkins to delete ACI after 10 mins and run the build prior to an hour or
What will be best approach to stop/delete ACI,  once the data is uploaded on storage account and start back prior to an hour?

Answer (score 0):

I have completed this request, took the approach as below:

1. Initial build and deployment is taken care by Jenkins to AKS via Virtual Node to ACI.
2. Build a Logic App with ACI connector to start and then trigger the API.
3. Another Logic App with event grid to trap the file is modified on storage account and then stop the ACI via ACI connector.
   This ensures my ACI is stopped once the work is completed and start back when needed.